# Rendering pixels from array of RGB values in SDL 1.2?

Tags: c++, rendering, sdl, pixel

I'm working on a NES emulator right now and I'm having trouble figuring out how to render the pixels.  I am using a 3 dimensional array to hold the RGB value of each pixel. The array definition looks like this for the 256 x 224 screen size:

```
byte screenData[224][256][3];
```

For example, `[0][0][0]` holds the blue value, `[0][0][1]` holds the green values and `[0][0][2]` holds the red value of the pixel at screen position `[0][0]`.

When the vblank flag goes high, I need to render the screen.  When SDL goes to render the screen, the screenData array will be full of the RGB values for each pixel.  I was able to find a function named `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom` that looked like it may work for what I want to do.  However, all of the examples I have seen use 1 dimensional arrays for the RGB values and not a 3 dimensional array.

What would be the best way for me to render my pixels?  It would also be nice if the function allowed me to resize the surface somehow so I didn't have to use a 256 x 224 window size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the data as an **unidimensional `char` array**:

```
int channels = 3; // for a RGB image
char* pixels = new char[img_width * img_height * channels];

// populate pixels with real data ...

SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom((void*)pixels,
                img_width,
                img_height,
                channels * 8,          // bits per pixel = 24
                img_width * channels,  // pitch
                0x0000FF,              // red mask
                0x00FF00,              // green mask
                0xFF0000,              // blue mask
                0);                    // alpha mask (none)
```

Comment: I have a window and I have a surface, how do I update the window to use the surface I have? There is not setSurface() or updateSurface() function.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.0, use `SDL_Texture` + `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING` + `SDL_RenderCopy`, it's faster than `SDL_RenderPoint`.

See:

- official example: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/e12c38730512/test/teststreaming.c
- my derived example which does not require blob data and compares both methods: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/0607da1236030d2e1ec56256a0d12cadb6924a41/sdl/plot2d.c

Related: [Why do I get bad performance with SDL2 and SDL_RenderCopy inside a double for loop over all pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214556/bad-performance-with-sdl2-and-sdl-rendercopy)