# Is there a reasonable limit to how many images SDL can render?

Tags: c++, memory, sdl, sdl-2

I'm creating a particle simulator using SDL, and I'm rendering rects from a dynamic array/vector. When the simulator reaches 500 particles, I start popping the particles in the vector. at 500 particles, the memory used is at 16 MB. However, SDL is having the worst time trying to render all 500 particles, even though they are 1 pixel in length and width. The framerate goes from 60 fps at 200 particles to 10 fps at 500.

How can I ease the tax on RenderCopy? Here's a snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DynamicParticles.size(); i++)
{
  //make particles fall 1 pixel each frame
  DynamicParticles.at(i).Advance();
      
           
        
  SDL_RenderCopy(Main_Renderer,
                 DynamicParticles.at(i).particle_texture,
                 NULL, &DynamicParticles.at(i).location);
}
```

Here `DynamicParticles` is a vector holding a `class Particles`. This class takes up about 15 MB when 500 items are present, and `RenderCopy` only takes the texture member and dstrect member.

[image]

Comment: Why was I downvoted? If you're here to see this can you explain what is wrong here?

Comment: I just want to know if SDL can handle this much.

Comment: Not the downvoter but I suspect asking for performance help with secret code might be a little unpopular around here.  Maybe producing the simplest case that exhibits your performance trouble would help.

Comment: 1-pixel elements hardly count as *rectangles*. All of the overhead could be in there (~30K per element!). Is simply plotting single pixels an option?

Comment: Well, particles have to be a single pixel. http://www.notdoppler.com/frame/639.html this is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: How do you know they are 1 pixel? it only says to advance them 1 pixel. (However, if they are all moving together in one direction, it could just be one texture. Even if they are moving in different directions, they could be drawn onto one texture if the motion is predictable.)

Comment: @dwn: OP says so in the post, no reason not to believe it.

Comment: Ahh, well then, I suppose I'll have to agree :)

Comment: @dwn What? I said in the question that each particle is a pixel, I'm not sure how I could draw them all on to one texture even if they are moving in the same direction.(they are not, Advance() just applies increasing gravity and random jitters)

Comment: That demo is not running for me in Chrome or IE, which is odd.

Comment: Do you have Java enabled? (nevermind i added an image of the demo(30000 particles))

Comment: I just did a test with 100,000 pixels, directly plotting them. Seems to be no problem so far. Doubling that is visibly slower, but there is still plenty room left for optimization.

Comment: Maybe cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214556/bad-performance-with-sdl2-and-sdl-rendercopy

Comment: @Jongware Hmm, did you plot them from an array holding 100,000 SDL_Rects? EDIT: I'm now reading dawn's post, may be helpful.

Comment: @dwn Thanks, the post proved to be helpful for my problem.

Comment: I don't think that the other post's answer is very helpful for the actual question even if it works for single pixel particles.  SDL_RenderCopy is not currently optimized for repeated calls and redundant renderer state changes.  It does what it does, but don't ever use it when you want good performance.  For that, code to OpenGL directly or use a wrapper that does at least use simple VBO optimizations.